# Definition of ordered triple

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why this is not a correct definition for ordered triple? (I know that the correct definition is **Kuratowski's definition**)

for any $a,b,c$ : $<a,b,c> = \{ \{a\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, b, c\} \}$

At the first time I saw the definition of ordered pair I thougt this is correct but according to kuratowski's definition it is not and I don't know why.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Oh I couldn't find it. Now what can I do with this post?

Answer (score 2):

This definition is not good because that way we would get that $(1,2,2)=(1,2,1)$. We don't want that to happen.